# what does $Proxy309 mean in eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging, proxy

when i debug and choose to "watch expression" from eclipse, I get in the debug "expressions" window

for one variable (that is injected by spring)
myService= $Proxy309

but for another local variable i get

myObject=MyObject

what does the $Proxy309 mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring AOP proxies your beans with CGLIB.

Read this for a full explanation:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying

Comment: is that the default behaviour or does it proxy the beans only on demand ?